# Python: how to return all results in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

```
def pop(n):
    result,counter = 0,0
    while counter<=n:
        result=(2**counter)
        counter=counter+1
    return result

example:
>>>pop(4)
16
```

How do i return all the results? like:

```
1
2
4
8
16
```

Comment: pop is a built in function, you should avoid using it's name for your own function

Comment: @Kraay89: no, it isn't.

Comment: `mylist = [1,2,3,4]`, `mylist.pop()` will work? What are you getting at? Am I using the wrong words? cause it is a valid python function... :S

Comment: @Kraay89, `pop` is not a "builtin" function. it is a *method* to the `list` class, but defining your own `pop` function will not shadow that, and so is not a problem.

Comment: I'm a bit ashamed right now, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

You can store the result in an list:

```
def pop(n):
    result,counter = [],0
    while counter<=n:
        result.append(2**counter)
        counter=counter+1
    return result
```

Now the result will be a list of all powers.

Alternatively, you can create a generator to `yield` multiple results

```
def pop(n):
    result,counter = 0,0
    while counter<=n:
        yield 2**counter
        counter=counter+1
```

Now if you do a `list(pop(4))`, then you will get a list of all results

Comment: You probably meant `yield` instead of `yeild` :)

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way would be something like this:

```
def pop(n): return [2**x for x in range(n)]
```

Comment: More information on list comprehensions here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. Your example is right there...